# How to add a 'Functor' object from prolog to a JSON in python

Tags: python, json, prolog

I'm consulting a Knowledge Base in Prolog and when I print it in python the outputs are functor objects that are not serializable, therefore, I cannot convert them to a JSON.

I've tried to convert the output with python libraries but I'm still unable to get the expected result that I get when I run the prolog code by itself.

```py
def build_response(message):
    try:
        # Prolog function to be consulted
        string = "color("+ message +")"

        pl = Prolog
        pl.consult("color.pl")
        response = pl.query(string)
        response_list = list(response)

        print(response)
```

I expect:
A = [ (a, red), (b, green), (c, red)...

The actual output is:
'A': [Functor(176397,2,a,red), Functor(176397,2,b,green), Functor(176397,2,c,red)...